# What counts as a magical effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic

My players obtained a [Robe of the Archmagi](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Robe%20of%20the%20Archmagi#content), which grants them this

> You have advantage on Saving Throws against spell and other magical effects.

What qualifies as a magical effect? Is it only effects of spells?

What about those of magical items?

> [Arrow of Slaying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/arrow-of-slaying): The creature must make a DC 17 Constitution saving throw, taking an extra 6d10 piercing damage on a failed save, or half as much extra damage on a successful one.

Or abilities of creatures, like [Dragons](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ancient%20Red%20Dragon#content)?

> Frightful Presence: Each creature must succeed on a DC 21 Wisdom saving throw or become Frightened for 1 minute.
>
> Fire Breath: Each creature in that area must make a DC 24 Dexterity saving throw, taking 91 (26d6) fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

Or effects of potions?

> [Potion of Poison](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Potion%20of%20Poison#content): If you drink it, you take 3d6 poison damage, and you must succeed on a DC 13 Constitution saving throw or be Poisoned.

Related: *[How do I know if an ability is magical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113364/how-do-i-know-if-an-ability-is-magical)*