# Should Invisibility be Inherently Magical?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature

There are several abilities in 5e that allow users to go invisible without casting a spell or using a magic item. Examples of which are: Empty Body (monk), Channel Divinity: Cloak of Shadows (Way of Shadow Monk), Cloak of Shadows (Trickery Cleric), Umbral Sight (Gloom Stalker Ranger), and Misty Escape (Warlock). None of these explicitly say 'magically invisible.'

Should I say that all forms of invisibility are magical when I am a Dungeon Master even though the book says otherwise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know if an ability is magical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113364/how-do-i-know-if-an-ability-is-magical)

Comment: Also here is [a link to a list of many other already existing questions about *antimagic field*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bantimagic-field%5D+%5Bdnd-5e%5D+is%3Aquestion). Though know that I am unsure about the duplicate I've put forward as your question is about invisibility as a whole, not some specific feature.

Comment: Oh but welcome to the site! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and visit the [help] if you have further questions. With the recent edit to your question I'm afraid it may be closer as primarily opinion based. This part of the site is not meant for chat-style discussion, which is often prompted by a question such as "Should I do X?"

Comment: I say not duplicate. *"Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell that’s mentioned in its description?"* is dubious here — where is invisibility just a state of being invisible, and where does it count as spell mentioned? This could be evaluated in a good answer.

Comment: After the edit, your question seems to be aware of the answer to "Is invisibility inherently magical" (i.e. no), so it's not a duplicate. It is instead asking something that is entirely a matter of opinion: whether you should house-rule otherwise (I assume for reasons of verisimilitude?). Such a question is not really answerable since it's primarily opinion-based, and might be a better fit for [chat]. That said, a much more answerable question might be to ask what the mechanical impact of such a house-rule would be (e.g. whether it'd break anything or have any unintended effects).

Comment: What do you mean by "inherently magical"? What's the practical impact of treating it as magical or not?

Comment: I'm going to move it to the Role-Playing Games Chat and rephrase the question to help me understand what is going on better. Do I need to delete this post?