# Is a creature standing in an Antimagic Field subject to the effects produced by Control Weather?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, antimagic-field, weather

Say, for example, that a person is standing in an Antimagic Field when a nearby disgruntled Druid decides to create a 5 mile radius freezing hailstorm via Control Weather.

Would that person be subject to the effects of the hailstorm? More specifically:

- What happens to the hailstones that enter the Antimagic Field?
- What localized weather effects does the person experience? Is the weather within the Antimagic Field somehow the hypothetical weather conditions that would have existed if Control Weather hadn't been cast?
- Is the person subject to the effects of extreme cold like the rest of the people within the hailstorm?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Hailstones will enter the [Antimagic Field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field)

Let's look at the relevant text of both spells. First, [Control Weather](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/control-weather) (**empahsis added**):

> You **take control of the weather** within 5 miles of you for the duration. ...
>
> When you cast the spell, you **change the current weather conditions**, which are determined by the DM based on the climate and season. You can **change precipitation, temperature, and wind**... When the spell ends, **the weather gradually returns to normal**.

The magical effect is that you have control over the weather. You aren't creating magical precipitation, temperature, and wind, just altering the current weather.

And now the relevant parts of Antimagic Field:

> Within the sphere, spells can't be cast... Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and **can't protrude into it**

We're not casting Control Weather within the field, so we're in the clear. But wait, spells can't protrude into the field. How does that apply to Control Weather? Changing temperature inside the Sphere would certainly count as part of the spell, so that's prevented. However, the sphere doesn't stop gravity, so precipitation that begins falling above the sphere will fall as normal weather does and enter the field.

Answer (score -4):

### No

Refering to [How do I know if an ability is magical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113364/how-do-i-know-if-an-ability-is-magical) we can see that [Control Weather](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Control%20Weather#content) is a magical effect because it's a spell. And we know that within an [Antimagic Field](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Antimagic%20Field#content):

> Spells and other magical Effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the Sphere and can't protrude into it.

So:

> Would that person be subject to the effects of the hailstorm?

No

> What happens to the hailstones that enter the Antimagic Field?

They don't.

> What localized weather effects does the person experience?

See below.

> Is the weather within the Antimagic Field somehow the hypothetical weather conditions that would have existed if Control Weather hadn't been cast?

Yes.

> Is the person subject to the effects of extreme cold like the rest of the people within the hailstorm?

No.

Don't try to rationalize this too much: magic is magical and it can do things that make no sense. Effectively this is no different from what occurs at the 5-mile radius limit of the spell.