# Would immunity to non magical fire damage protect me from an Azers fire damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-resistance, damage-types

I have immunity to non magical fire. Nothing in the Azers description indicates that its ever-present flames are magical. Am I therefore immune to its fire damage?

Comment: It's pretty rare in 5e for damage resistances to specify magical/non-magical resistance for anything that isn't Slashing, Piercing, or Bludgeoning. Can you specify what feature is giving you Immunity to Fire Damage that is specifically indicating non-magical fire only?

Comment: Our DM has handed out boons granting a resistance to one type of non magical damage to each of the 5 PCs. Poison, cold, lightning, acid, and i got fire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes, you are protected

If a feature in 5e cares whether or not stuff is magical, there's a [litmus test](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113364/how-do-i-know-if-an-ability-is-magical).

Since the Azer's magic flames don't meet any of the bullet points on that list they, like dragon fire or the attacks of a fire elemental, are just fluffed as magic and don't actually count as magic for rules mechanical purposes.