# Can a Fairy PC fly in an Antimagic field?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, unearthed-arcana

The Unearthed Arcana for the Fairy Race states:

> **Fairy Flight.** You have a flying speed equal to
> your walking speed and can hover. This flight is
> magical and does not require the use of your
> wings (if you have them).

By calling this flight magical, does this mean that a fairy cannot fly while in an antimagic field?  I can't think of any other creatures that have 'magic' flight other then by casting *fly* on them, does the Fairy's flight function the same as the spell in this case?

Comment: Note that the non-UA published versions are different: flight *does* use your wings and isn't specified as magical.  (*Mordenkainen Presents: Monsters of the Multiverse* and *The Wild Beyond the Witchlight*) - [Can fairies fly in an antimagic field?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/210771)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### The flight is magical, so it is suppressed within an *antimagic field*.

Since the rules clearly state the flight ability is magical in nature then it will not function inside of an antimagic field which specifically blocks all magic:

> A 10-foot-radius invisible sphere of antimagic surrounds you. *This area is divorced from the magical energy that suffuses the multiverse*. Within the sphere, spells can’t be cast, summoned creatures disappear, and even magic items become mundane. Until the spell ends, the sphere moves with you, centered on you.
>
> *Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can’t protrude into it.* A slot expended to cast a suppressed spell is consumed. While an effect is suppressed, it doesn’t function, but the time it spends suppressed counts against its duration.

Their flight isn't quite the same as the *fly* spell though as the spell gives the target a flight speed of 60 feet while the fairy has a fly speed equal to their walking speed. This will be slower by default, but could be higher if they have a sufficient bonus to their walking speed.

Comment: You could add "Does its description say it’s magical?" criteria from the Sage Advice https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/113365/27377

Answer (score 4):

Note: a previous version of this answer held an opposite opinion based on incorrect information, which I no longer agree with.

## Fairy Flight is suppressed

The first two paragraphs of [Antimagic Field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) indicate that it is likely intended to affect all magical effects except the absolute most powerful kinds (artifacts and divine intervention basically). More importantly in this case, it also provides a list of *very specific* ways it affects *very specific* types of magical effects. This case falls under the "Spells" heading:

> Any active spell **or other magical effect** on a creature or an object in the sphere is suppressed while the creature or object is in it.

Even though Fairy Flight is not a spell, and thus someone (like myself) may incorrectly assume the information under the "Spells" heading is not applicable, the actual text says "Any [...] magical effect on a creature [...] is suppressed". Fairy Flight is a magical effect as you noted, and it is definitely on a creature, thus it is suppressed within an Antimagic Field and the Fairy will be unable to fly.

Comment: I read your answer firmly believing the opposite, but my faith was shaken a bit. I'm not 100% convinced the Fairy's flight wouldn't be a Targeted Effect, but this actually is a good, surprising answer. +1

Comment: *Antimagic field* suppresses all magical effects: “ Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere”.

Comment: Antimagic field also says *"Spells **and other magical effects**, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it."* List gives descriptions for specific interactions, but does not remove the general rule in the text above.

Comment: @Mołot Despite the first paragraph of this answer, the spell description pretty clearly does say “all magical effects stop working.”

Comment: This contradicts the Sage Advice https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/113365/27377

Comment: @enkryptor I disagree, I cannot find anything in that Sage Advice which addresses *how* Antimagic Field interacts with magical effects which don't fit any of its listed categories. I never disputed that the effect *is* magical. In fact, that Sage Advice indicates that Dragons are "magical things" and if Antimagic Field worked on all "magical things" then Dragons would stop existing in Antimagic Fields; I disagree with that interpretation, and thus I claim Antimagic Field does not interact with at least some "magical things".

Comment: Fairy Flight is a "magical effect on a creature" hence is a subject to be suppressed — *"Any active spell or **other magical effect on a creature** or an object in the sphere is suppressed while the creature or object is in it."*

Comment: @enkryptor Ah, I've missed that part. Thank you for finding something I missed.