# Can fairies fly in an antimagic field?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, flight, antimagic-field

Another [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/185324/31402) had raised this issue when fairies were part of Unearthed Arcana and indicated that they couldn't because the flight was magical.

However, I noticed that on [DND beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/814913-fairy#FairyTraits) that the flight is because of the fairy's wings, a non-magical source, and now I don't know what to believe.

The description of my flight from DND beyond says:

> Because of your wings, you have a flying speed equal to your walking speed. You can't use this flying speed if you're wearing medium or heavy armor.

The phrasing, 'Because of your wings,' makes me think the flight is now non-magical.

Comment: Hi there. Welcome! I am assuming from your referencing D&D Beyond, that you are referring to D&D 5e. If so, can you add that into the tags of your question. I'll answer your question, but if you're not referring to the 5e, or I will amend or it.

Comment: I'm new to this site, so I didn't realize those were tags. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: The previously linked question was about the UA version, so this is a different question.

Comment: What's the UA version?

Comment: Often before a feature is released they release a UA version which is effectively a test version which may be different from the actual released version. The question you referred to was about that pre-release version, which may be different to the version

Comment: UA is an abbreviation for "Unearthed Arcana"

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me

Comment: I've gone ahead and made some substantial edits to improve the formatting and clarity of your question. Can you affirm I did not change your intent.

Comment: That seems about right. Thanks. Sorry, I didn't have Internet for a couple hours and when I got Internet again I decided to play WoW for a while.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The racial trait of "Flight" for fairies is not magic per se.

In both *Mordenkainen Presents Monsters of the Multiverse* (p.14) and the *Wild Beyond the Witchlight* (p.12), the racial trait of "Flight" is non-magical. Therefore, it would not be affected by a spell such as Antimagic Field (PHB, p.213).

It states -as you rightly point out- that, "**because of your wings**, you have a flying speed equal to your walking speed", which incidentally is a speed of 30 feet.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Tasi you may want to hold off on accepting an answer and give a day or two for others to respond. You may receive alternative points of view that can be helpful.

Comment: I already pressed the accept button

Comment: @Tasi: You *can* uncheck the accepted answer if you want.  I wouldn't recommend it in this case (since the answer seems pretty straightforward to me), unless anyone else posts an even better answer.  Nothing's stopping them from doing so, just make sure you keep an eye on the question at least once a day for the next couple days, especially since it's on hot network questions so lots of people are going to look at it and might have questions for you in comments.