# Does Blessed Strikes count as a magical effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, cleric, optional-rules

In Tasha's Cauldron of Everything on page 31 the Optional Class Feature "Blessed Strikes" for Clerics is explained:

> *8th-level cleric feature, which replaces the Divine Strike or Potent Spellcasting feature*
>
> You are blessed with divine might in battle. When a creature takes damage from one of your cantrips or weapon attacks, you can also deal 1d8 radiant damage to that creature. Once you deal this damage, you can’t use this feature again until the start of your next turn.

Does this count as a magical effect?
Say, I'm in an anti-magic field and attack, does this feature still cause the extra damage?

Comment: Related: "[How do I know if an ability is magical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/113364)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No, it's not magical

The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf), in the question "Is the breath weapon of a dragon magical?", lays out a series of tests for whether or not a particular ability is *magical* for the purposes of the game's rules:

> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?

In the case of Blessed Strikes, the answer to all of these questions is no; it's not a magic item, is not a spell or replicating a spell's effects, doesn't involve a spell attack, doesn't require spell slots, and the words "magic" or "magical" don't appear in the ability's description. Therefore, Blessed Strikes are not a magical effect for game rule purposes and still work fine in an antimagic field.

As Sage Advice explains, the rules draw a distinction between what it calls the "background magic" of the D&D world and the "concentrated magical energy" that is involved in magic items, spells, and similar magical effects. As far as the rules are concerned, your cleric's ability to dish out radiant damage is just a part of how the world works and is no more magical than the ability of dragons to fly and breathe fire or whatever else.

Comment: Do you think it’s magical if it’s being used to boost cantrip damage?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov not even then. (Of course, the antimagic field would prevent the cantrip from taking effect in the first place, so it wouldn't be possible to trigger Blessed Strikes on a cantrip in an antimagic field.)