# Would a Tressym's detect invisibility be able to see through an Ice Mephits false appearance of the ice mephit doesn't move?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, barbarian, invisibility

I have a barbarian who is using his beast sense to see through his pet Tressym's eyes. The room in question is an icy lodge and has many ice Mephits that are watching but not moving. Do we think he would he be able to see/detect the Mephits with the Tressym's senses?

Ice mephit
False Appearance. While the mephit remains motionless, it is indistinguishable from an ordinary shard of ice.

Tressym
Detect Invisibility. Within 60 feet of the tressym, magical invisibility fails to conceal anything from the tressym’s sight.

Beast sense:
You touch a willing beast. For the duration of the spell, you can use your action to see through the beast’s eyes and hear what it hears, and continue to do so until you use your action to return to your normal senses.

Comment: What game are you playing?

Comment: Storm kings thunder

Comment: No, not which adventure, which game. D&D 5e? D&D 4e? D&D 3.5e? Pathfinder 1e? Pathfinder 2e? Something else entirely? Dale M is pretty convinced it's D&D 5e, I guess because Tressyms have detect invisibility and Ice mephits have False Appearance and barbarians have beast sense there, and Storm King Thunder must be a D&D 5e adventure, but if they're wrong, please fix the tags.

Answer (score 9):

### The mephits are *not* invisible

The Tressym can see them (so could anything else); they are just "indistinguishable from an ordinary shard of ice."

Being able to see invisible does not defeat False Appearance.

Comment: And to add to that, nothing about the mephit's ability appears to be magical. They're made of ice. They look like ice. [None of the checkboxes for magical abilities are ticked here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/113364/28941). So even if you had a companion that detected magic, or saw through *all* magic, or *all* illusions, they'd still just look like ice, because that's what they *are*. And Tressym are far more limited than that, since they explicitly only see through magical invisibility, not all magic, not all illusions, not even all invisibility (for innately transparent things).